# What are different between next(error) and throw new Error in Express framework?

Tags: node.js, express

Can someone explain to me about the different between two ways exception error handling in code Express JS below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {

  // the first way:
  throw new Error('my error message');

  // the second way:
  next(new Error('my error message'));

});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message || 'Internal Server Error');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Welcome to ExpressJS'));
```

It returns the same result handled by error middleware but what is the difference here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nothing, based on the source code.](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/ea537d907d61dc693587fd41aab024e9df2e14b1/lib/router/layer.js#L94-L98)

```
  try {
    fn(req, res, next);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
```

Comment: Seems like calling next(err) yourself is a bit cleaner since you avoid kicking in the exception handling. I prefer that to trusting the internal implementation won’t change one day.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I don't think that will ever change for Express. After all, what would happen to uncaught exceptions then?

Comment: True. But why not directly call next? I don’t see any benefit to throwing. It’s not wrong to, but adds no value and is slightly more expensive

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Being able to throw adds value when your handler isn't just a simple function where `next` is always available in scope.

Comment: @AKX I’m not arguing with that, but in the case you have the next function, why not use it?

Comment: It is important to note that this only applies to synchronous code. If you work with `async/await` functions, `next()` must be used instead of `throw new Error()` to handle errors by express.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a scenario in which the next function made sense to me.
I created a middleware to check for required params in an express route, and when I had a case in which two or more required params were not satisfied, throwing an Error would stop the request at the first error.
With next function, it does not stop on the first error and I actually got messages informing about all of the params that I needed to satisfy, which was what I wanted to do.
The code snippet:

```
export const validateParams = (params: string[]) => {
    return async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        for (const field of params) {
        if (!request.body[field]) {
          next(new MissingParamError(field))
            // instead of 
            // throw new MissingParamError(field)
        }
      }
  return next()
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) return response.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
  };
};
```